# Clicking a span or div class with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to click the span class "status status-online" or the text within the div class "Online". I would like to use jQuery for this, as I am trying to put this in the Chrome Console. Here is the HTML for the site:

```
<div class="theme-dark"><div class="popout popout-top-left" style="z-index: 1000; overflow: hidden; visibility: visible; left: 80px; top: 878.533px; height: 210px; width: 217px; transform: translateY(-100%) translateX(0%) translateZ(0px);">
    <div class="status-picker popout-menu">
        <div class="popout-menu-item ">
            <div class="status-icon-text">
                <span class="status status-online" style="margin-right: 14px;"></span>
                <div class="status-text">Online</div></div>
                </div>
```

Please provide a solution to this in jQuery or Javascript(so I can use tampermonkey). I have tried to research this but whenever I couldn't find a solution that selects the span, I only found ones that select div IDs and this doesn't have that.

Thanks,

I have tried:

```
$('.status status-online').click();
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:27
```

Comment: to select the span with the class 'status status-online' you can do $('.status status-online') to select it

Comment: Hi Nick, that is working. But, I am trying to click it. I tried Koby's comment: $('.status status-online').click();
but that returns:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:27

Comment: `"I couldn't find a solution that selects the span, I only found ones that select div IDs"` - So change the selection logic in what you found to match what you need?  It's unlikely that you'd find on Google the *exact code* that will work on *your custom HTML*.  But you can *modify the code* to do what you want.  Did you try that?

Comment: David, I tried: $('.status status-online').click(); but it says:   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null at <anonymous>:1:27

Comment: @qttqtt: Pro tip: When you're asking the community to help you resolve an error in your code, showing them the code and the error might be a good start.  Perhaps try including that information in your question?

Comment: I added it David

Comment: @qttqtt: Is jQuery loaded at all?  What does `$('span')` return?

Comment: @David That returns: <span class="dms"></span>

Comment: Please watch a basic Jquery course https://www.udemy.com/learn-how-to-code-jquery/

Comment: @qttqtt: That makes no sense.  (1) That code isn't in the HTML you're showing.  (2) The jQuery function returns jQuery objects, not just strings.  There's something else going on that you're not including here.

Answer (score 0):

you can find any element in page width this code using "jquery":

```
var elem =$(".ClassName");
```

in your example you should find it with below code:

```
var elem = $(".status-online");
```

no important what kind of "Html" is ypur element : "span", "Div", "input" or others.

Comment: for click function in your example you should do this: $(".status.status-online").click();

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:27

Comment: are you using "."(dot) before two class name? without any spaces between them?

Answer (score 0):

Using **jQuery** you can do it with the [`.click( handler )`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) function, that Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

- The event handler can be bound to any `<span class="status status-online">`:

```js
$( ".status-online" ).click(function() {
         alert( "Handler for .click() called. on clicking the Span element" );
         });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <span class="status status-online" style="margin-right: 14px;cursor: pointer;">Click Me i'm a span</span>
```

---

The click event is only triggered after this exact series of events:

- The mouse button is depressed while the pointer is inside the
  element.
- The mouse button is released while the pointer is inside the element.

This is usually the desired sequence before taking an action. If this is not required, the mousedown or mouseup event may be more suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the information and the code, but it says this:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:27

Comment: Yes, i see your one works. Maybe because on the site, the Online doesn't appear as it is in a dropdown menu? Once the menu is clicked the Online appears on the page.

Comment: Yes, the problem is in the style, you're applying on the div above the span